# Variable of unspecified type in C#?

Tags: c#, types, sha

Is it possible for me to declare a variable, without a type, then specify the type based on some conditions? For example, I want to create a SHA Hash object based what size the user would like to use:

```
        //get the Sha hasher
        var shaHash;

        switch (this.HASH_ALGORITHM)
        {
            case HashAlgorithm.SHA256:  //HashAlgorithm is an enum.
                shaHash = SHA256.Create();
                break;
            case HashAlgorithm.SHA384:
                shaHash = SHA384.Create();
                break;
            case HashAlgorithm.SHA512:
                shaHash = SHA512.Create();
                break;
        }

        //... do hashing
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Implicitly-typed local variables must be initialized. So var shaHash; is a compile error.

Comment: @CodeNaked, yes, my code will not get passed the compiler.

Comment: exactly. But what are you trying to accomplish that you won't gain trough declaring the base class instead?

Comment: @Kelrond, the base class will work fine in my case. Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, that won't work. But, given that all three of those types inherit from `System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm`, you could declare the variable of that type:

```
HashAlgorithm shaHash;

switch(this.HASH_ALGORITHM)
{
    // snip
}
```

**Edit**

Just to add, the reason that `var shaHash;` will not work is because that `var` is just a shorthand way of saying "I'm not sure of the best type to use here, so please infer it for me". The compiler requires that you specify an initial value so that it can determine the best type to use.

Answer (score 2):

Not without resorting to `dynamic`; you need to use inheritance or interfaces for this. So the type could be e.g. `object`, or if the different `SHA` classes have another common superclass or if they implement some interface, you could use that superclass or interface. Otherwise, you could create [adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) classes with a common superclass and wrap the `SHA` objects in the adapters.

Answer (score 2):

Use base type:

```
HashAlgorithm shaHash = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not posible. In order to use `var` you need the compiler to know what will the type of your variable be and that is only posible when you assign a value. Also you cannot say `var varname = null;` because null does not define a type.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a parent class in which you declare a type, and 3 other classes which inherit after the parent class (children), then you can create a method which would be declared as returning the parent type, but inside you would return each of the child types. 
This will work and compile as the parent type will be automatically casted on to a child type.
It will not work the other way round however (you cannot cast a type from a child to parent).

Answer (score 0):

In c# 4 you can declare a [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) type.

Comment: You can, but you shouldn’t use `dynamic` in this case.

Comment: Yeah you are right he should use the base type they all inherit from.